# Bot Framework Teams Messaging extension search

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am currently creating a messaging extension in teams right now and I am using the search messaging extension. I have already it working and set up a card. Now , my question is it possible to create my own template ? because I would want to modify the search logic by adding a drop-down box to make a user select on whichever field they want to search. Let's say if the user selects a work item on a drop-down then the search will query only the work items else if the user selects articles then the search will query the articles items alone. I want to achieve that kind of concept if possible? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Search based messaging extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/define-search-command) commands only support text inputs and you can't change input field to drop down.

You could use [action based messaging extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/define-action-command) commands which gives you flexibility to build [Task Module with embedded web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/define-action-command#choose-how-to-build-your-task-module).